# Copy database to a new server

Tags: sql-server-2016

Is it possible to copy a database to a new server? I just want to have the database on a new server because I need to make some tests. I didn't have much experience with servers.

Comment: Why would it be impossible? have you changed the SQL version? First plz tag your dbms!

Comment: Generate script and run it on other machine where ever you want.

Comment: this is was i made. but the data aren't there. Then i tried to script the data which didn't worked.

Comment: Backup your database, then restore it on the new server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this steps :

- Run your **SSMS**
- Right click on the `database` you want to copy
- In the Popup menu , go to `Taches` , then click `Offline`
- Right click on the `Database` again in the popup menu  , `Taches` -> `Detach`
- Open the folder `..\MSSQL\DATA` , copy `Yourdb.MDF` and `YourDB_log.LDF` files to the folder of the new `Instance`.
- Now you can `Attach` both `Databases` and work on it in both instance.

**Another way:**

- Run Your **SSMS**
- Right click on the `Database` you want to copy
- In the popup menu , `Taches` -> `Copy the database...`
- Follow the steps on the `Wizard`

You can select option if you want to keep the database ONLINE when it is being copied.

You can also select option of MOVE or COPY database as well.

When the process is over it will show the success message and database will be copied to another server.

**Note:**

1- The Copy Database Wizard is not available in the Express edition.

2- The Copy Database Wizard cannot be used to copy or move databases that are/have:

- System.
- marked for replication.
- marked Inaccessible, Loading, Offline, Recovering, Suspect, or in Emergency Mode.
- data or log files stored in Microsoft Azure storage.

Also , a database cannot be moved or copied to an earlier version of SQL Server.

**Updtae:**

If there is no `Copy database option` , then you can **Copy Databases with Backup and Restore**.

For more information about it [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190436.aspx).

Comment: if I had the option Copy the database i wouldn't ask this question.

Comment: I got the database without data on the new server. how can I script the data?

Comment: And if you edit your question , and add details, then we can help you

Comment: I'll have nearly 0 experience from SQL.

Comment: I can't just copy the data sets because i got foreign keys which didn't work then anymore.

Answer (score 1):

No experience? No problem, backup the database.
Copy it into the target machine.
Restore DB from device >> open the DB backup file.

At this point you have the entire DB without missing any schema objects such as foreign keys.

Finally delete all sql logins that the DB came with and recreate them manually as you test access.
Once you are comfortable with this operation you can go ahead and get more experience using some of the techniques describe above which are recommended if you have a large DB to restore and so on.

How to restore the DB on SQL Server Management Studio
Steps:
1.  On “Object Explorer” panel right-click on “Databases” and selected Restore Database

2. Select “Device” and browse database location. 
   note: Copy the .bak file locally before restoring.
3. The DB information will auto-populate the window, you can edit the name of the DB to be restored.
4. Go to the “Files” page and check the “Relocated all files…” box.
   Select existing folder locations for Data and Log files.
5. HIT OK